# model in partial view is null - asp.net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using asp.net core 2.1.

My Main page in under Pages folder and my partial view which is _test2 is in shared folder.
This is my Main page:

```
public class MainModel : PageModel
    {
        public IRepositoryStudent irep;
        public MainModel (IRepositoryStudent _irep){
         irep = _irep;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public Student student{ get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            student = irep.GetFirst();
        }
    }
```

This is my Main.cshtml:

```
@page
@model APWeb.Pages.MainModel

<h2>Main</h2>
<partial name="_test2" model="Model.student" />
```

This is my partial view : _test2:

```
@page
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@

@model Student
@{ 
<h1 >@Model.Name</h1>}
```

my model in partial view is null and I have this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
APWeb.Pages.Shared.Pages_Shared__test2.get_Model()
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I resolved my issue bye removing '@page' from partial view.

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day! This was exactly what was required. :)

Comment: This is such a ridiculous simple solution, which I doubt was mentioned in the docs that I was reading. :facepalm:

Answer (score 1):

The partial view need to be a view page rather than razor page.
here is a demo worked:
Main page:

```
public class MainModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Student1 student { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            student = new Student1 { Name = "Moddy" };
        }
    }
```

Main.cshtml:

```
@page
@model ModelValidation_MVC_.Pages.MainModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Main";
}

<h1>Main</h1>
<partial name="_test2" model="Model.student" />
```

_test2.cshtml:

```
@model ModelValidation_MVC_.Models.Student1

<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
```

Student1.class:

```
public class Student1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Your code is same as mine with one difference which was the key: removing @page from partial view.Thanks anyway,